# Merge two proj transforms into one (rotated lat/lon to EPSG)

Tags: coordinate-system, pyproj

I have a question that I assumed would be straightforward, but I'm unable to properly solve it. I have points on a rotated lat/lon grid, and I want to get their coordinates in another CRS. Currently, it seems that the only way I can manage to do this is via a double transform: (1) perform the opposite rotation to get to a regular lat/lon format, (2) move the regular lat/lon coordinates into the new CRS. An example:

```py
from pyproj import Transformer

origin_lon = 10
origin_lat = 47
# Transform COSMO rotated grid coordinates into unrotated coordinates
rotated_to_unrotated = Transformer.from_crs( 
    '+proj=longlat',
    '+proj=ob_tran +o_proj=longlat +lon_0=-180 +o_lon_p={} +o_lat_p={}'\
    .format(-180+origin_lon, 90-origin_lat), 
    always_xy=True)

# Transform unrotated coordinates into the desired CRS
unrotated_to_CRS = Transformer.from_crs( 
    '+proj=longlat',
    'epsg:3035',
    always_xy=True)

# Perform the two rotations in successive order
coordinates=[(0,0), (1,1)]
transformed_coordinates=[]
for pt in rotated_to_unrotated.itransform(coordinates):
    transformed_coordinates.append(unrotated_to_CRS.transform(*pt) )
print(transformed_coordinates)
# >> [(4320999.999999999, 2654053.479931807), (4432566.859410212, 2765225.490478056)]
```

The coordinate transformation is correct and really fast; but it's just not very neat to have to use two coordinate transformations rather than one. How can this be done in a single step?

Answer (score 1):

Right, I fixed it. It turns out I had the projection 'backwards'. The following code shows how to do it in one step:

```py
from pyproj import Transformer

origin_lon = 10
origin_lat = 47
# Transform COSMO rotated grid coordinates into unrotated coordinates
rotated_to_unrotated = Transformer.from_crs( 
    '+proj=longlat',
    '+proj=ob_tran +o_proj=longlat +lon_0=-180 +o_lon_p={} +o_lat_p={}'\
    .format(-180+origin_lon, 90-origin_lat), 
    always_xy=True)

# Transform unrotated coordinates into the desired CRS
unrotated_to_CRS = Transformer.from_crs( 
    '+proj=longlat',
    'epsg:3035',
    always_xy=True)

# Perform the two rotations in successive order
coordinates=[(0,0), (1,1)]
transformed_coordinates=[]
transformed_coordinates2=[]
for pt in rotated_to_unrotated.itransform(coordinates):
    transformed_coordinates.append(unrotated_to_CRS.transform(*pt) )
print(transformed_coordinates)
# >> [(4320999.999999999, 2654053.479931807), (4432566.859410212, 2765225.490478056)]

# Transform COSMO rotated grid into the desired CRS
rotated_to_CRS = Transformer.from_crs(
    '+proj=ob_tran +o_proj=longlat +lon_0={} +o_lon_p=-180 +o_lat_p={}'.format(-180+origin_lon, 90+origin_lat),
    'epsg:3035',
    always_xy=True)
for pt in rotated_to_CRS.itransform(coordinates):
    transformed_coordinates2.append(pt)
print(transformed_coordinates2)
# >> [(4320999.999999999, 2654053.479931807), (4432566.859410212, 2765225.490478056)]
```

Comment: Should I rotate COSMO_REA6 files,
or use the RLAT RLON in COSMO_REA6_CONST_withOUTsponge.nc described under
https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/REA/COSMO_REA6/help_COSMO_REA6 ?
More generally, do you know of a cosmo_rea6_util.py (without cdo) ? Thanks

Comment: Hi @denis, I don't know what your question is exactly, but I'd generally recommend using `cdo` where applicable, e.g. `cdo remap{con/dis/nn}`, as it works very well and is super fast. The rotation I perform here is purely for plotting purposes, the data itself is not touched.